# Double integral problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the double integral
$$
I = \iint_D x y \ dx dy
$$
where $D$ is the closed triangular region with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(4, 0)$, $(0, 3)$.

Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Do you have an attempt...?

Answer (score 2):

$x$ ranges from $0$ to $4$, and for each value of $x$, $y$ ranges from $0$ to $-3x/4  + 3$, so
$$
I = \int_0^4 dx \ x \int_0^{-3x/4 + 3} dy \ y.
$$
I'll let you evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this question with [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_theorem). If you have the vector field $\mathbf{F} (x,y)$, you know that
$$\int_{D} (\mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{F})_z\,dx\,dy =\int_{\partial D} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}. $$

With $\mathbf{F}=- \tfrac12 x y^2 \mathbf{e}_x$, you find that
$$\begin{align}
\int_{D} xy\,dx\,dy& = \int_{\partial D} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}
= \underbrace{\int_0^4 F_x(x,0)\,dx}_{=0}
+ \underbrace{\int_0^3 F_y(4,y)\,dy}_{=0}
- \int_0^1 [4 F_x(\mathbf{r}) + \underbrace{3 F_y(\mathbf{r})}_{=0}]\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 2 [4(1-t)][3(1-t)]^2\,dt = 72 \int_0^1(1-t)^3\,dt
\end{align}$$
where we parameterized the last segment via $\mathbf{r}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}4(1-t)\\ 3(1-t)\end{pmatrix}$, $t\in[0,1]$.